# Hide preference button on one preferences page

Tags: android, preferences

I built a preferences xml that I use as resource in two different activity pages.

The only problem is that I don't want the LOGOUT button to show in one of those two pages (because the user is not connected yet).

What I did now is:

```
logoutButton = (Preference)getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("logout");
logoutButton.setEnabled(false);
```

the button now shows up in gray.. but is there a way to not make it show at all??

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have your preference inside a category?

Comment: Did my solution work? It should.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your logout button (Preference) is in the PreferenceScreen, do this:

```
PreferenceScreen screen = getPreferenceScreen();
Preference logout = findPreference("logout");
screen.removePreference(logout);
```

Else if your logout button (Preference) is in a PreferenceCategory (which is inside a PreferenceScreen), do this:

```
PreferenceCategory category = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("category_name");
Preference logout = findPrefence("logout");
category.removePreference(logout);
```

Comment: This worked fine for me, I had a task to display preference or not in the category depending on the system locale. Solution from @mik3y didn't work as the preference was not in the root of the hierarchy, but inside PreferenceCategory. It was the last preference in the category so I don't need to worry about the order when adding/removing it dynamically.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (busy couple of days), but thanks for the excellent solution works nicely!

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Views, Preferences don't have a setVisibility method.  Instead, try using [PreferenceScreen#removePreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceGroup.html#removePreference%28android.preference.Preference%29):

```
PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = getPreferenceScreen();
logoutButton = (Preference) preferenceScreen.findPreference("logout");
preferenceScreen.removePreference(logoutButton);
```

You may need to retain a reference to logoutButton in your activity if you later wish to add it back.

Answer (score 0):

put some condition and add this to the oncreate method for example

```
if(something){
    CheckBoxPreference lp=new CheckBoxPreference(this);
    lp.setKey("checkbox");
    lp.setTitle("logout");
    lp.setEnabled(true);
    getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(lp);
    }
```

if I put something at true the preference shows otherwise it doesn't. Don't put it in the xml just in code